# c# LINQ creating anonymous type from run-time information

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a List of columnNames that is populated at run-time.  How would I use a LINQ expression to create average values for each of those columnNames, inside a grouped by query such as:

```
        var result = from data in view.AsEnumerable()
                     group data by new {Group = data.Field<string>("group_no")}
                     into grp
                     select new
                     {
                         Group = grp.Key.Group,


                         //Add anonymous values for eachcolumn average
                     };
```

As far as I can tell you cannot enumerate within an anonymous scope?

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: That wouldn't make sense; you wouldn't be able to do anything with the object.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Instead, you can make a dictionary:

```
Averages = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(
    c => c.ColumnName, 
    c => grp.Average(dr => Convert.ToDouble(dr[c]))
)
```

The `Convert.ToDouble` is needed since I don't know what tyhpe the coulmn is, and `Average` needs a specific numeric type.
If all of the columns are the same numeric type, you can replace that with a cast.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this won't work as some columns are strings. I only want the average on a select number of columns within a datatable.  However, those columns are only known at run-time.

Comment: @Darren: Wrong; `Convert.ToDouble` will parse strings.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer - I know that it will parse strings, however the string contain letters.

Comment: Then you can call your own parser instead, or add a `Where` clause to filter out those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types are created at compile-time. You cannot create one from runtime information. Moreover, anonymous types have method scope, meaning that you couldn't return them and use them somewhere else.

Depending on what you're trying to do (what are you trying to do, by the way?), you might look at dynamic types. Start with (e.g.) ExpandoObject. Alternatively, generating a compiled type at runtime might make sense. Look at (e.g.) TypeBuilder.